# Download a file with urllib and specify where to save it

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I want to download a ".exe" file using urllib in python. Here is my code I found on the internet until now:

```
from urllib import request

url = "https://example.com"
download_file_name = "example.exe"

def download(url, download_file_name):

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, download_file_name)

download(url, download_file_name)
```

I got an error, "NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined". urllib is imported so why is there still an error?

Also, can I change/specify the location where the .exe is saved after download?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import `urllib`. You imported the name `request` from `urllib`. You can specify where the file is saved by giving the full path to `download_file_name`.

Try this:

```
from urllib import request

url = "https://example.com"
download_file_name = "C:\\example.exe"

def download(url, download_file_name):
    request.urlretrieve(url, download_file_name)

download(url, download_file_name)
```

However, the whole point of `urlretrieve` is to download a temporary file. It is saved in a temporary location and eventually deleted. You can discover where it has been saved by checking the result of `request.urlretrieve`:

```
url = "https://example.com"
tmp_file = request.urlretrieve(url)
print("Temporary file was saved at " + tmp_file)
```

Comment: thank you so much, is there an oportunity to download it as a permanent file? Does a method for this exist in python?

Comment: You could se `urlopen` instead.

Comment: urlopen() downloads the file too? the name is confusing than. 
I do not need to add a read() method after urlopen()?